# SugerCRM web service responce returns null in iOS

Tags: ios, web-services, sugarcrm

My SugerCRM app service calling returns null when I call the get_entry_list method, my json request like this

```
{
    "input_type" = JSON;
    method = "get_entry_list";
    "response_type" = JSON;
    "rest_data" = "{\n  \"deleted\" : 0,\n  \"session\" : \"a5rk9ej583533cggigrke3u186\",\n  \"link_name_to_fields_array\" : [\n\n  ],\n  \"order_by\" : \"\",\n  \"query\" : \"\",\n  \"offset\" : 0,\n  \"module_name\" : \"Accounts\",\n  \"max_results\" : 2,\n  \"select_fields\" : [\n\n  ]\n}";
}
```

if there is any error please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i had success without escaping the double-quotes.
you could try simple quote around the rest_data like :

```
"rest_data" = '{\n  "deleted" ...
```

i have tested it with module login.
regards